# Dijit Select Not clickable in Chrome windows 8

Tags: google-chrome, select, windows-8, dojo, onclick

I have the following problem, when I try to click the dijit select to select an option, it doesn't give any response. This only happens in Chrome in Windows 8, the issue is that I'm using the dojo embed in Websphere 8.0 so upgrade for the moment is not an option, can someone help me:

Window 8 (32bits)
Chrome 36.0.1985.143 m
Dojo: 1.7.2_IBM (27793)
Case test: ​http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.5/dojo-release-1.7.5/dijit/tests/form/test_Select.html
(The link is for dojo 1.7.5 but I managed to reproduce the problem in this version)

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I created the problem, but it seems to be random, in a virtual machine with windows 8.1 and chrome 37 seems to work but in my laptop windows 8.1 and chrome 36 is giving the problem, I also tried in a tablet with windows 8.1 and chrome 37, and It wasnt giving the problem but now it stated again.http://jsfiddle.net/4tm1btg5/